# Input group in shiny framework

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap-3, shiny

I am trying to make input group in the *html* page produced by the *shiny* app. I would like to have input box and button side by side for planed **select and confirm** way of using, either by simulating or using *bootstrap's* *input-group* class. I am still failing to write right code to achieve this.
I do not want to use scaffolding for this.
Thanks for any advice.

In the snippet below the two inputs render row by row. I need it tightly in group side by side.

#### App snippet

copy and paste to your R console

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
ui=fluidPage(
div(class="input-group",
selectInput("sel",label=NA,choices=LETTERS,width=150),
actionButton("btn",label="go"))
),
server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
)
```